# Error al enviar mensaje a WhatsApp con el Api oficial por medio de un templeate Media Image

Tags: c#, api, whatsapp

Estoy intentando enviar un mensaje con la api de WhatsApp, es por medio de un templeate que recibe una imagen y parametros en el body.

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Unexpected key \"namespace\" on param \"template\".","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"A0BvLn46mpxOvK7fW8SabWf"}}
```

El namespace de mi plantilla la obtengo del siguiente apartado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya valide el nombre de mi plantilla , el namespace , los parametros, etc.

Alguna sugerencia?

Les agradezco su respuesta y ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacer un llamado para enviar un mensaje y pasarle los parámetros.
En este caso el parámetro [0] es de tipo text y recibe el valor: "contenido del parametro"

```
'{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "template_name",
        "language": {
            "code": "es_AR"
        },
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "body",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "contenido del parametro"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}';
```